# $dx=\frac {dx}{dt}dt $. Why is this equality true and what does it mean?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

$dx=\frac {dx}{dt}dt $. I know that this deduction is obvious from the chain rule, given that we treat our dx and dt as just numbers. But I find it quite unsatisfactory to think of it in that sense. Is there a better / more "calculus-inclined" way of thinking about this equality. Can you please explain both the LHS and RHS individually.

Comment: Differentials should never be treated as numbers. There are examples where you simply get the wrong answer.

Comment: @MattSamuel From a mathematician's point-of-view you are absolutely correct. But since calculus is aimed towards engineering and physics students, this way of thinking of derivatives as infinitesimal quantities is quite useful. It gives you a lot of motivation to set up the right equation.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you define $dx$ and $dt$.

Comment: @JustinThong  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  It addressed precisely the rigorous definition of a differential.  I don't understand the disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

Statements like $dx = \frac{dx}{dt} dt$ are best viewed as mnemonic devices, and nothing more (until *way* down the mathematical road, potentially, if at all, maybe).

They are helpful *for remembering techniques* when it comes to separable differential equations, for example, or the first derivative of a parametric equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}.$$

But, do not buy into this notion too seriously. This analogy *will* break down. For example,

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}} \neq \frac{d^2y/dt^2}{dx^2/dt^2}.$$

Comment: "until way down the mathematical road, potentially, if at all, maybe" that's a very safe way to go about it :)

Comment: @hjhjhj57 My thoughts exactly! I've heard talk of these "differential forms", but have not made it there myself; I was indeed alluding to your answer there.

Comment: My first approach to differential forms was with David Bachman's book.  It's quite accessible and very geometrically oriented if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would think about it.  Imagine you are at the blue dot in the graph below and you are moving along the curve one unit to the right (ΔX = 1).  Where will this leave you?  You can find out where you will be by taking the slope at the blue point (ΔT/ΔX) and multiplying by ΔT

[image]

Comment: I think this is misleading. While that's where the notation comes from historically, you shouldn't treat $\frac{dx}{dt}$ as a ratio...

Answer (score 0):

There are two good ways to think about this.

First - integration (which is usually what this type of notation is shorthand for).

If $x=x(t)$, then
$$dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt=x'(t)\;dt$$
is shorthand for
$$x(T)-x(0)=\int_{0}^{T}x'(t)\;dt,$$
which is something you can readily verify in a fully rigorous way.  Let $\Pi=\{0=t_{0},t_{1},\ldots,t_{n-1},t_{n}=T\}$ be some partition of the interval $[0,T].$
Then,
$$\begin{align*}
x(T)-x(0)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x(t_{k})-x(t_{k-1})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x'(t_{k}^{*})(t_{k}-t_{k-1})\;\;\;\;(t_{k}^{*}\in(t_{k-1},t_{k}))\\
&\to\int_{0}^{T}x'(t)\;dt\;\text{as}\;n\to\infty.
\end{align*}$$
(Note how the first expression is unaffected by the limit $n\to\infty$.)

Intuitively, you can get $\Delta_{[0,T]} x$ by adding up a bunch of $dx$'s or a bunch of $\frac{dx}{dt}dt$'s.

In the second line we use the mean value theorem (or linear version of Taylor's theorem), which says
$$x(t+\delta t)-x(t)=x'(t^{*})\delta t$$
for some $t^{*}_{k}\in(t,t+\delta t)$.

This leads us into the second interpretation, which is a fully computable/rigorous approximation to the expression using only finite quantities/concepts you are already familiar with.

If we switch to Leibniz notation and evaluate $dx/dt$ at $t^{*}$ then we have
$$\delta x=\frac{dx}{dt}\delta t,$$
and you can see that this is basically the expression you are trying to verify the validity of.  However, we do not typically know $t^{*}$ and anyway, the expression is suggesting we can evaluate $dx/dt$ at $t$.  But if we do that we only get something slightly different:
$$\delta x=\frac{dx}{dt}\delta t+o(|\delta t|).$$
The expression above is computable (since we know all of the quantities involved), except the error term which obeys the bound $\leq C(\delta t)^{2}.$

Essentially, your expression $dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$ is the above when $\delta t\to0$ (note that the error term goes to $0$ and the remaining expression should be true).  Literally though, both sides ends up going to $0$ in the limit (this is obvious).  What is actually important is how the ratio behaves, and that is what the expression is really trying to communicate.  Indeed, dividing by $\delta t$ we get
$$\frac{\delta x}{\delta t}=\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{o(|\delta t|)}{\delta t}.$$

The error term still goes to $0$ as $\delta t\to0$, and the result is
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}.$$

Comment: $\delta x = x'(t) \delta t$ isn't the same as $dx = x'(t)dt$. You need to formally define what $d(\cdot)$ means.

Comment: I don't follow you - did you read the entire response?

Comment: Yes, but $\lim_{\delta t \to 0} \delta t$ = 0.

Comment: Correct, so you didn't read it apparently.....

Comment: You're right, didn't read it close enough. Let me delete my previous comments and elaborate a more precise comment.

Comment: Ok, my objection basically is: under this perspective, *what is* $d(\cdot)$?

Comment: No precise meaning, and none is needed really.  The point of my answer (the second part anyway) is to view the differentials in the expression as quantities $\delta x$ and $\delta t$ - when they are finite, you get the same form of the expression plus a small error; as you send the quantities closer to $0$, the error disappears, but so do the quantities - you fix this by dividing and examining the ratio (which in turn leads right back to the first interpretation).  Thinking of $dx(\cdot)$ as a linear functional of $\delta t$ is likely beyond the scope of the OP's knowledge.

Comment: I see, let's hope this helps the OP. Personally I always disliked this kind of intuitive explanations, which in my opinion lack rigour, that's why I objected immediately (wrongly in my firsts comments). Of course this doesn't mean it's wrong what you're saying or that it may be useful to look at it this way.